# Space handling in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following rows in the table

```
Record_Value
E1X4B1  20160822
E1XBA1  20160822
E1    X920160822
```

I need to select the values X4,XB and X9. I wrote the query :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Record_Value,3,2)
```

It selects only X4 and XB. To select the value X9 (which is in the 7th position) I thought of using the coalesce function but it handles only NULL values and not BLANK values. Can you please guide me. Expected Output would be

```
X4
XB
X9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TRIM` to remove the leading blanks (and trailing...):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(Record_Value),1,2)
```

Answer number 2, to the edited question, ANSI SQL compliant:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING(Record_Value FROM 3)) FROM 1 FOR 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Yes it works but unfortunately that was not the correct record. I just inquired from my team mate and the row has other values apart from the one I mentioned. I am sorry. I have edited my question. The trim command does not work now :(

Comment: Actually SUBSTR will also work : SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(SUBSTR(Record_Value,3)), 1,2)

Comment: So `SUBSTR(Record_Value,3)` means from 3rd character? I thought it was return 3 characters (from first position), that's why I didn't dare to use it. Anyway, the `SUBSTRING` version is ANSI SQL, and perhaps more portable.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution simply removes *all* spaces before the substring:

```
SUBSTRING(OTRANSLATE(Record_value,' ','') FROM 3 FOR 2)
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. I will use this for other similar queries.